# Update a record in SQL but not overwrite....add text at the start

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Please how I can update table where is some text?

Example:
I have text "said hello" and I want to make this "Peter said hello" - I want to add word Peter...

understand?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try something like :

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET FIELD = CONCAT('Peter ',FIELD) WHERE CONDITION;
```

Comment: I tested: UPDATE zbozi SET zbozi_nazev = CONCAT('Tapeta ',zbozi_nazev) WHERE CONDITION but: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONDITION' at line 1

Comment: you need to add a condition (ex where id = 1) if you want to run the query on all fields just do the following :

UPDATE zbozi SET zbozi_nazev = CONCAT('Tapeta ',zbozi_nazev)

Comment: if you need to add "Peter" at the end use: CONCAT(FIELD, 'Peter ')

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
update your_table set field = concat('Peter ', field) where ...
```

Comment: I tested: UPDATE zbozi SET zbozi_nazev = CONCAT('Tapeta ',zbozi_nazev) WHERE CONDITION but: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONDITION' at line 1

Comment: what goes after `where` is the conditions the rows must match for the update to take place. If you want to update the whole table with the same prefix, don't specify a `where` clause at all. Otherwise write the `where` condition like you would for a `select` statement (and read the MySQL `update` docs).